# Airflow 2.2 user login failed in LDAP

Tags: ldap, airflow-2.x

I have setup LDAP with airflow using [this article](https://robust-dinosaur-2ef.notion.site/Airflow-with-LDAP-in-10-mins-cbcbe5690d3648f48ee7e8ca45cb755f#26bcef44783e40efa49aa2aca5b45716)

I configured the Webserver.config  however at the time of login using LDAP user in airflow UI, I get an error

> Login Failed for user "User".

Strange that the login is working fine for LDAP bind user. in Security tab of airflow UI, I am getting only two users: Admin and Bind user.

I have checked that LDAP is setup correctly with group giving members if queried using a python script